# Чи існує український відповідник слова "techie"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Нещодавно виконуючи переклад наткнувся на англійське слово "techie" в значені "людина, яка цікавиться технікою". Переглядаючи англо-українські словники, я знайшов переклад "технік", однак в академічному словнику це слово не має потрібного значення.   Цікаво, що російською мовою його можна перекласти як "технарь" і означає "человек, который интересуется техникой". Отож, питання: чи є в українській мові слово-відповідник, яке б мало таке саме значення і його можна було б використовувати для перекладу?

Comment: А що кажуть словники? Ви десь шукали? Ми заохочуємо наших користувачів демонструвати спробу самостійно відповідати на запитання. Це додає контексту, робить запитання цікавішими і стимулює інших до відповідей.

Comment: В усіх онлайн агло-українських словниках слово перекладалося як "технік". Проблема в тому, що в академічному українському тлумачному словнику визначення цього слова не підходить по значеню, адже означає людину яка професійно займається ремонтом або розробкою технічних засобів, чи є студентом навчального закладу технічного спрямування. В російкому ж варіанті "технарь" має значення "человек, который знает и любит технику". Отже, чи є в українській мові слово, яке б означало "людина, яка б цікавилась технікою"?

Comment: Чудово. Тоді, будь ласка, відредагуйте [edit] запитання, щоб усі оці пояснення стали частиною запитання, а не коментарем. А коментарі ми потім видалимо, коли вони стануть зайві.

Answer (score 1):

[Кембриджский англо-русский словарь](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/techie)

> techie - человек, интересующийся техникой, **технарь**

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Технарь, разг. – **технар**.
>   *[— Мене як математика, технаря цікавило: для чого потрібна взагалі мова? Ну що з того, що зникне мова? (Леонід Плющ)]*

[Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53410/998798.html)

> ***Технар*** -я, ч. , розм. **1.** Фахівець із технічного обслуговування літаків.
>   **2.** Той, хто працює в галузі техніки, технічних наук.

В українській мові є слово ***"технар"***, але дещо з іншим значенням ніж в російській. На жаль, точного відповідника до означення *"людина, яка цікавиться технікою"* не знайшла.